# As British citizen travelling on Australian passport do I need to get Australian passport endorsed before leaving UK?

Tags: dual-nationality

I just got my naturalisation certificate as a British citizen. I want to travel to Australia and retain my right to abode. Do I need to apply for certificate of entitlement endorsing my Australian passport before I leave Uk or can I travel to Australia and simply apply for a British passport from there and re-enter Uk at any time with that? I am confused about having to apply for certificate of entitlement before leaving UK. Is that absolutely necessary? Need a response soon please

Comment: A certificate of entitlement can take up to six months to get and costs £372. A passport takes about six weeks and costs about £75.Times might be longer due to COVID-19. How soon do you need to travel?

Comment: Planning to travel in 2 months but passport applications are only being taken on priority basis. Cant I just go on my Australian passport and return on UK passport after applying for it overseas?

Comment: Who said that passport applications are only being taken on a priority basis?

Comment: I can't find anything on GOV.uk that says you can't apply from Australia, but you'd have to be there long enough for the passport to be issued. Bear in mind that applications from Australia are now handled directly by the passport office in Liverpool, so add international postage/courier times to whatever processing time you expect.

Comment: @Michael Hampton https://www.gov.uk/apply-first-adult-passport “Do not apply unless you’re travelling before September 2020 or you need a passport urgently for compassionate reasons.” Premium and Fast track services are currently unavailable

Comment: @Traveller Yes, exactly!

Comment: Thanks for all your responses. I have sent a web query to passport office. According to Australian High Commission,  have to travel to Australia on my Australian passport so leaving UK is not an issue. I am only concerned about re-entry.